# How to parse JSON using GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

My Json response is something as below and confused how to parse it using GSON.
Please have look on the following and guide me how i can parse it using GSON.

```
{
  "GetMICSDataResult": {
    "CONVERTIONFACT": [
{
        "CONVERSIONFACT": "1",
        "ITEMNO": "S1300W",
        "UOM": "Ea."
      },
      {
        "CONVERSIONFACT": "1",
        "ITEMNO": "S1300Y",
        "UOM": "Ea."
      }
    ],
ITEMDETAILS": [
      {
        "ITEMDESC": "FluorescentDeskLamp",
        "ITEMNO": "A11030",
        "LOCATION": "1",
        "PRICELIST": "WHS",
        "QTYONHAND": 164,
        "UNITPRICE": 38.3,
        "UOM": "Ea."
      },
      {
        "ITEMDESC": "FluorescentDeskLamp",
        "ITEMNO": "A11030",
        "LOCATION": "2",
        "PRICELIST": "WHS",
        "QTYONHAND": 247,
        "UNITPRICE": 38.3,
        "UOM": "Ea."
      }
]
```

}
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: you Json is not in a proper format... please provide a proper Json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is easy way to do that. Just use POJO generator http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ it will give you plain object with necessary annotations. also you can use Json formatter to validate your json https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ - the JSON you posted is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourClass class = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, YourClass.class);
```

Comment: Got an error com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path

Comment: When your Json begins by "{" it s an object one when it begin by "[" it s an array one. As suggest by the others you should verify your structure on a json validator.